# How to access css styles consisting of multiple words with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

For example, if a programmer wanted to set the text-align property with javascript as follow :

```
document.getElementById("title").style.text-align = "center";
```

The browser engine interprets it as another sign (minus probably) and sends an error. How can coders access these styles consisting of multiple words using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS property names get the hyphen removed and subsequent words capitalized in JavaScript.

```
text-align
```

becomes:

```
textAlign
```

However, to make things even simpler, try to steer away from using inline styles and instead apply and remove pre-made CSS classes when possible using the [`.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Thank you. I never used classLists, so I will try to learn it.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.